# Creating SQL Servers on VMWare

Tags: sql-server

Can you recommend a good self service solution for creating SQL Databases? Our dev and test teams need to frequently create new databases. I would like to keep these databases as close to production configuration as possible but I would like them to be able to create this on their own without me being in the picture? We are a VMWare shop, so I prefer solutions that work with VMWare.

[Edit - Clarifying the question. Need to install a SQL server from scratch. Create a new VM, Install SQL and create a new DB]

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: How is VMWare relevant? They create databases on a SQL Server instance, which they must connect to using SSMS/PowerShell/C#/what have you, and that instance is running on Windows. Whether Windows is physical or virtual shouldn't really have any bearing...

Comment: What's stopping you from adding their logins to the [dbcreator role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176014(v=SQL.90).aspx) or granting the [CREATE ANY DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx#Security) permission so they can run the appropriate build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at ScaleGrid SQLDirector (http://www.scalegrid.net/sqldirector.htm). Its a database as a service for the private cloud. We support VMware, HyperV and XenServer.

PS: I work for ScaleGrid.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will try out the Beta and compare it to vCloud Director.

Comment: I spent some time looking at both the solutions. vCloud Director is a little too heavyweight for what I am looking for. I played around with ScaleGrid SQLDirector and its pretty cool. It integrates directly with VMWare and also has a self service console :)

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment, I'm not entirely sure this question is a good fit for this site but:

- [VMWare vCloud Director](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmware-vcloud-director-DS-EN.pdf) for self-service VM creation.
- If you're SQL2008R2+ you can [SYSPREP a SQL installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210754%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Alternatively, the standard install process shouldn't be a challenge for a SQL literate developer or sysadmin.
- As for creating a database... anyone that can't do so probably shouldn't be coding against SQL Server.

If you're a Microsoft shop and your developers are MSDN licensed, you might want to expand the scope of this idea and take a look at [Visual Studio 2010 Lab Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee712698.aspx).

> Visual Studio Lab Management is an extension of Microsoft Test Manager
>   that helps you to optimize the use of Microsoft Hyper-V technology to
>   manage and use virtual machines in testing, building, and developing
>   applications in Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio Lab Management is
>   integrated with System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM) to
>   enable you manage multiple physical computers that host virtual
>   machines and to manage the storage of virtual machines, virtual
>   machine templates, and other configuration files in SCVMM library
>   servers.